# GUI Using Seesaw

Tags: clojure, seesaw

I am trying to make a small window using Seesaw for Clojure. I have created a project "sample" using Leiningen.

```
lein new app sample
```

I have made added the dependency in the project file.

```
(defproject sample "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"] [seesaw "1.4.4"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot sample.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

My source file is as follows:

```
(ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [seesaw.core :as seesaw]
            [seesaw.dev :as dev]))

(def window (seesaw/frame
             :title "First Example"
             :content "hello world"))

(dev/show-options window)
```

But when I run it I keep getting an error: `clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: dev, compiling:(C:\Users\A\sample\src\sample\core.clj:10:1)`

Comment: How do you run it? I guess you already visited some tutorials as https://gist.github.com/daveray/1441520

Comment: Is there a reason you're AOT-compiling the code?  I don't see anything there that would require AOT.  Does it work without AOT?

Answer (score 0):

I followed your instructions and it worked fine for me, so long as I left the -main definition in place.